# Sum column in last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the sum of the column Value in column Total grouped by Year, Month and Day, but the sum must be in the "last" row of the group

```
Year  Month   Day   Value  Total

2017    5     10     10      0
2017    5     21     5       0
2017    5     28     3       18
2017    6     15     8       8
2017    7     14     9       0
2017    7     18     2       11
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain how you are getting those values (presuming you want to calculate `total`).

Comment: The question was aswered yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the total on the last record for each month.  You can do this using ANSI standard window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by year, month order by day desc) = 1
             then sum(value) over (partition by year, month)
             else 0
        end) as total
from t;
```